# Forumla in sharepoint field not producing correct value

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

Hello and thank you for looking at this. I'm trying to use this:

```
=IF(Age<=5,"0",IF(Age>=6,"1w",IF(Age>=10,"2w",IF(Step="Sent and Uploaded","0"))))
```

It will never display 2w. Is there a better way to do this?

Please & Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula instead:

```
=IF(Age<=5,"0",IF(Age>=10,"2w",IF(Age>=6,"1w",IF(Step="Sent and Uploaded","0",""))))
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))

Answer (score 0):

Switch the `Age>=6` and `Age>=10` positions. It is because it always satisfies the `Age>=6` condition all the time